# how to iterate inside the elements of a quosure of rlang in R

Tags: r, purrr, rlang

So let's say that I want to now if `X` appears in the quosure.

```
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
q <- quo(mean(X))
```

I know I can check for equality with expr

```
q[[2]][[2]] == expr(X)
[1] TRUE
```

But how do I iterate or flatten the quo element? `flatten(q)` doesn't work, I couldn't use for loops, no idea how to use some map function from `purrr`.

Ideally I would like to capture X when it's "data" and not any function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following custom function to convert expressions to their [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (ASTs):

```
getAST <- function( ee ) { as.list(ee) %>% purrr::map_if(is.call, getAST) }
```

Since you're working with quosures, there's an intermediate step of retrieving the associated expression:

```
## Define a quosure
## Side note: don't use q as a variable name; it conflicts with q()
qsr <- quo( mean(5*X+2) )

## The associated expression
xpr <- rlang::get_expr( qsr )

## ...and its AST
ast <- getAST( xpr )
# List of 2
#  $ : symbol mean
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ : symbol +
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ : symbol *
#   .. ..$ : num 5
#   .. ..$ : symbol X
#   ..$ : num 2
```

From here, you can use standard techniques to find `X`. For example, flatten the nested list and compare each element to `expr(X)` as in your question:

```
purrr::has_element( unlist(ast), expr(X) )
# [1] TRUE

purrr::map_lgl( unlist(ast), identical, expr(X) )
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: That's really cool!, and how about the fact that the X I want to capture shouldn't be a function? That means that X will be part of a final list (without any list inside) and that it won't be indexed with [[1]], right? (If I'm right, how do I extract only the end lists to do this?)

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. For one, functions can themselves be passed as arguments to other functions. For example, in `summarize_at( mtcars, "wt", sum )` the function `sum` is an argument to `summarize_at` and will appear as a terminal leaf in the AST. Second, compare `getAST( expr(X) )` and `getAST( expr(X()) )`. They both produce the same AST, making it impossible to distinguish `X` from `X()`. If you're interested in testing whether something is or isn't a function, I recommend using the built-in `is.function()`.